# How pass two parameters to url (without GET)?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

A while back I was given the advice to not use the GET approach in my urls when using Django as it's cleaner this way.

That works pretty nice with one parameter:

```
(r'^call/add/(?P<call_id>\d+)/$', call_view),

http://127.0.0.1:8000/call/add/1/
```

But how could I possibly use the same approach with two parameters?

As I am still learning, please enlighten me about better approaches. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply can add another on the back like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/call/add/1/foo/2`. You have to add the second parameter to the regular expression as well like `(r'^call/add/(?P<call_id>\d+)/foo/(?P<foo_id>\d+)$', call_view),`.

You have to change the controller as well: `def call_view(request, call_id, foo_id):`

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiple parameters as follows:

```
(r'^call/add/(?P<call_id>\d+)/(?P<other_value>\d+)/$', call_view),
```

and you view should look like this:

```
def call_view(request, call_id, other_value):
    # view code here
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(r'^call/add/(?P<call_id>\d+)/(?P<receiver_id>\d+)/$', call_view),

http://127.0.0.1:8000/call/add/1/903256
```

and you need to add `def call_view(request, call_id, receiver_id):` in views.py

or you can you  `w+` instead of `d+` to pass string a a variable

```
(r'^call/add/(?P<call_id>\d+)/(?P<receiver_name>\w+)/$', call_view),

http://127.0.0.1:8000/call/add/1/Kave
```

For more info : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/